# Javascript, How should I refactor my local storage approach to send values to a different computer

Tags: javascript, html, web

Good evening,

I am currently running a website. On my website, when one of the user's clicks on a link, HTML is stored in local storage for that user and the link opens up in a new tab, and grabs the HTML that is stored in local storage, to render the page on the new tab. The issue is that, If the user sends the URL to someone else, the person who received that URL, will not be able to view the page, because the HTML for the page is stored in the local storage for the first user. What is the best way to fix this, so that the User who recieves the URL can view the webpage?

What i can think of right now is instead of using local storage, making an API call that sends back the HTML when a user visits the link.

Comment: Probably your second solution will do, it is called SSR - server-side rendering.

Comment: not really exactly what SSR is, and also I was wondering If anyone knew of a solution without making an API call? also will take the best solution

Comment: Have you considered using a UI framework? could be just what you need. Real web routing is old and not suitable for web applications.

Comment: yes I am using a UI framework, this is a super special use case however

Comment: I would do that differently if possible, especially for dynamic pages. If that's not a dynamic page, maybe just build a page and put it inside you assets.